# Layer Panda DataFrame on top of each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have three DataFrames like this:

```
groups:
    0   1   2   3
0   e   f   g   h
1   e   f   s   h
2   q   f   g   r
3   e   r   g   b

items:
    0   1   2   3
0   ret sef sdf fhs
1   hnf cbv awd øjg
2   gry bcr vbd dgf
3   xfh sjd krt qeb

weights:
    0   1   2   3
0   241 234 343 34
1   23  276 334 42
2   561 256 35  345
3   234 654 754 234
```

I want layer these on top of each other to get a MultiIndex with groups as first index, items as second and weights as values. Eg. in 0,0 I have "e" (first index), "ret" (second index), and 241 (value), or in 2,3 I have "g", "krt" and 754.

How can I accomplish this? I would like to do this without iterating over the datasets, and do it the "Panda way".

This is not the same as question [Combine multiple pandas DataFrames into a multi-index DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960864/combine-multiple-pandas-dataframes-into-a-multi-index-dataframe), because I want it to look like this:

```
e ret 241  <-- from 0,0 in each dataframe
  hnf 23   <-- from 0,1 in each dataframe
  xfh 234  <-- from 0,3 in each dataframe
q gry 561  <-- from 0,2 in each dataframe
```

and so on... Meaning that I put the dataframes on top of each other and create a three dimensional dataframe, "looking through them".

Comment: John Zwinck: I believe you have misunderstood the question, as I dont want the same outcomes the question you refer to.

Comment: I tend to agree, there is some unstacking that needs to go on, plus the index is new, not present in the original DataFrames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unstack all of your DataFrames, then use `set_index`.  I decided to `sort_values` so that all of your corresponding index values are next to each other.

---

```
out = pd.concat([groups.unstack(), items.unstack(), weights.unstack()], 1)
out.sort_values(by=0).set_index([0, 1])
```

```
         2
0 1
b qeb  234
e ret  241
  hnf   23
  xfh  234
f sef  234
  cbv  276
  bcr  256
g sdf  343
  vbd   35
  krt  754
h fhs   34
  øjg   42
q gry  561
r sjd  654
  dgf  345
s awd  334
```